# Storing a handle in a cell array matlab

Tags: matlab, callback

I have a class which inherets handle.
This class manages (among others) a dropdown box, whose callback should call an instance function.
The instance function looks like this:

```
function dropDownBox_Callback(src, eventData, obj)
    Redraw(obj);
end
```

I am trying to pass obj as parameter for the callback, as such:

```
uicontrol(obj.panel,'Style','popupmenu','CallBack', {@dropDownBox_Callback, obj});
```

However I get the error

```
Conversion to cell from double is not possible.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the error is coming from `{@dropDownBox_Callback, obj}`? Seems unlikely given the message text, and it's certainly [supported](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/creating_guis/f16-999606.html#f16-1001315).

Try the following:

```
h = uicontrol(obj.panel,'Style','popupmenu');
callbackFcn = {@dropDownBox_Callback, obj};
set(h, 'Callback', callbackFcn)
```

If there is an error, which line does it occur on?